# SplashScreen logo paddings

Tags: android, splash-screen, layer-list

I found this [totourial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) where described how to implement right splash-screen. I have wide image resource and when I implemented that SplashScreen I sought that that picture has no paddings in **ldpi** screens. I've tried a lot of things but nothing cannot add paddings to that `Bitmap`. Please, help me to do that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

try inserting the image in few different resolution so in ldpi the picture would be smaller and still have the pending